# Assigning an array to a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have just started learning C from David Griffiths Head first C book and I am confused in the section on pointers.

**The problem** :

This makes sense

```
char msg[] = "hello";
```

This also makes sense

```
char *ptr_of_msg = msg;
```

because array variables are similar to pointers

But how does this work ? :

```
char *ptr = "hello";
```

The thing on the right side is an actual array, how can it be assigned to a pointer ?

Comment: A string is just an array of characters.  A string literal is the same just pointing to a memory location in the assembly assumed to be readonly.

Comment: 1) TL;DR: your first and third examples are simply equivalent.  2) You said "array variables are similar to pointers".  More specifically, "arrays can decay to a pointer".  Look here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461580/421195

Comment: @paulsm4 They aren't equivalent; `msg` is modifiable, the string pointed to by `ptr` is not

Comment: Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays, though on access, an array will be converted to a pointer to its first element. [6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) An array is a specific object where all elements are guaranteed to be sequential in memory. A pointer is just a normal variable that holds as its value a memory address where something else can be found. Your "How does this work?" is simply `char *ptr;` and `ptr = "hello";`. Separate the declaration from the assignment and it becomes clear.

Comment: There's a couple of nuances here that are a little special that i don't know are really covered in the duplicate. The first one is that `msg` is actually getting a COPY of "hello" allocated into memory, and then is pointing to the copy. That's a special case when you instantiate an array. Once an array is instantiated, you'll can't just use = to copy over members. Second big one is what Govind pointed out: `*ptr` is pointing to the read-only string "hello". You won't be able to modify its members (unless memory is weird on your system).

Comment: @yhyrcanus I believe the standard explicitly makes it read-only (though I don't have the exact section/paragraph reference at hand)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i think one would usually expect something like : `*ptr = "hello"` or `ptr = &variable` but I guess the string literal is just equivalent to its pointer

Comment: @Matthew so this means that it only works for strings and not for say int because "hello" is pointing to a location in memory while 4 would just be 4 ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal

Comment: Let's complicate this further `"hello"` is a *String Literal*. Technically it is an array. It is created in read-only memory on all but a very few systems. When accessed, it is converted to a pointer to the first character. So it has type `const char *`. When you declare `char *ptr = "hello";` due to historic C syntax, you are not required to make it `const` qualified, but it is better to do so. Either way, whether you assign the pointer to the first char in `"hello"` or `&somevar`, you are simply assigning an address to `ptr`.

Comment: Let me repeat, please [read this first](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). Literally (pun intended) all you need to know.